# numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U20'), dtype('int64')) -> None PYHTON

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

Whenever I try to run this code below, I am met with the the error:
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U20'), dtype('int64')) -> None

Im trying to open a `.data` file under the name `uploaded_numbers` and then overwrite the file that it was previously on with the new data number I have. I know the reading and the writing part works as I use it later in the program and it works perfectly.

Any help?

```
import numpy as np
import pickle

with open(r'W:\Python\NEA Dice Project\account_number.data', 'rb') as x:
    uploaded_numbers = pickle.load(x)
    print(uploaded_numbers)

uploaded_numbers += 1

with open(r'W:\Python\NEA Dice Project\account_number.data', 'wb') as x:
    pickle.dump(uploaded_numbers, x)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You wrote :

```py
with open(r'W:\Python\NEA Dice Project\account_number.data', 'wb') as x:
    pickle.dump(uploaded_numbers)
```

I think you probably forgot the 'x' parameter.

```py
with open(r'W:\Python\NEA Dice Project\account_number.data', 'wb') as x:
    pickle.dump(uploaded_numbers, x)
```

Aside from that, I'm afraid there isn't much help we can offer...
From the bit of code provided, there is no explicit use of numpy, we don't really know what's in your `.data` files, and only one line of the full trace-back triggered by your error...

*I wish I was able to write this in the comment section under your question, but I am not allowed to do so...*